# How do I get MySQL to output what its plugins write to stderr?

Tags: mysql

I need to debug a library that sends some data to a MySQL plugin, but I can't seem to make MySQL write anything relevant to stderr. I'm running MySQL like this:

```
$ export MYSQL_TEST_TRACE_DEBUG=1
$ sudo mysqld
```

Is this the right way to enable debug output for plugins, or do I have to do something else

Answer (score 0):

The `$MYSQL_TEST_TRACE_DEBUG` environment variable is lost in the sudo operation.

You can try: `-E` to "preserve environment"

Also cross-check your `sudoers` file to make sure there are not other restrictions on environment variables (like `setenv` or `env_reset`)